# How to make screen rendered as indexedStacked children scrollable

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, apk

I am building a flutter app

I build a stateless widget dat only return a scaffold with an appbar at the top

and a Colum as the body. the first child of the colum is a listview builder of three categories

So ontap of each of the categories I want to switch to the required screen

I also want to be able to slide left and right between each screens

```
<pre>
class Messengernavscreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final _controller = PageController();

  final List<Widget> _screens = [
    Messagescreen(),
    Onlinescreen(),
    Groupsscreen(),
    // Requestscreen()
  ];

  final List<String> categories = [
    'Messages',
    'Online',
    'Groups'
    /*'Request'*/
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    PageController(); // here i did as you said but the parameter controller and children does not exist inside pageController

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Palette.onsPrimCol,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Palette.onsPrimCol,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text(
          'Chats',
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 28.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          Circlebutton(
            //iconSurroundedMargin: 6.0,
            // iconSurroundedPadding: 6.0,
            bgColor: Colors.grey[200],
            icon: Icons.search,
            press: () {},
            iconsize: 30.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: width * 0.80,
            height: 45.0,
            color: Palette.onsPrimCol,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: categories.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        categories[index],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 22.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            letterSpacing: 1.2),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 2.0),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: PageView(
            children: _screens,
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

The widget you're looking for is a `PageView`. You give it a list of children, and then you can swipe between them:

```dart
PageView(
  children: [
    FirstPage(),
    SecondPage(),
    ...
  ],
)
```

If you also want to be able to set the current page using the bottomn navigation buttons, you can pass in a `PageController` and set the page using that:

```
final _controller = PageController();  // defined in your state class

// then in build()
PageController(
  controller: _controller,
  children: [ ... ],  // list of pages
)

// then to update the page manually:
void setPage(int page) {
  _controller.animateToPage(
    page,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    curve: Curves.ease,
  );  // note: no need to call setState()
}
```

This will let you swipe left/right between pages.

Comment: Thanks @cameron1024, it worked. I can now scroll left and right after changing indexedStaked to PageView. but talking about setting the page using the bottom navigation button, after I placed  "final _controller = PageController();" // inside the class

& I type PageController() inside build, the parameter you provided seems not to exist 
controller:  & children:

Comment: And secondly, I have two screens where I want to fixed this issue, one with a bottomnavigationbar the other with a horizontal aligned listview at the top. I want to fix the one with the listview builder at the top first.
So i have updated this question to include my code, pls check it for me, i want to be able to scroll left and right and also be able to click on any of the list view tab and get the required screen to display